# Files corrupted by NTFS compressed disk... files not readable

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs, compression

A time ago I formatted an HDD to be NTFS Compressed, and I stored there a lot of important files (Fireworks PNG files, zip files, rar files, php, html js files...).

Yesterday I opened a png file with fireworks, made some changes and saved it and now I cant open it!

the file appears to be damaged a lot of files were damaged, for some reason.

I wonder if somebody knows how to fix the files or get them back.

Comment: What is the SMART status of the hard drive?

Comment: Did you run a chkdsk on the disk?

Answer (score 2):

I would image the disk first if the contents are extremely valuable. Then run chkdsk, try to decompress them, then chkdsk again. Personally, I don't trust compressing files, and never do it. It is just one more thing that potentially can go wrong.